# How to call the frame from another class?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jframe, mouselistener

I have set my frame in my main named "Main" class. And now, I have another class named "Menu" and I want to make a mouselistener using the frame from the Menu class. My problem is how can I call or instantiate the frame from another class.?
Cause I want to make a mouseDragged using the frame.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a reference.  For more specific help, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of your best effort.